# Can you save the position of a node in an sks file

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

I'm trying to create a SKScene file where we create empty nodes at the places where our players and other objects will be placed. The problem is that the positions all have to be set in code. Is it possible to set the position in the sks file instead?
I did notice there is a Position label in the node inspector, but that doesn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: I am using Xcode 6 Beta 6

Comment: Why not use NSUserDefaults?

Comment: @sangony Well, Im working with SpriteKit, not the normal interface builder. Secondly, it's not integrated in the scene editor so I would have to edit that manually.

Comment: You can easily use NSUserDefaults in SpriteKit and coding it only takes a couple of lines.

Comment: @sangony I'll try it, and if you have time could you write up a little longer answer for other people? I'll report back when I get it working :)

Comment: @sangony could you give an example, because I have no idea how to get this working. Also, would it be possible to reuse the .sks files that I already have or do I need to do this with NSUserDefaults alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write data with [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSDictionary *nodeDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myNode.position.x], @"posX",
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myNode.position.y], @"posY",
                          nil];

[defaults setObject: nodeDict forKey:@"nodeDict"];

[defaults synchronize];
```

Read data with NSUserDefaults:

```
NSDictionary * nodeDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nodeDict"];

float posX = [[nodeDict objectForKey:@"posX"] floatValue];
float posY = [[nodeDict objectForKey:@"posY"] floatValue];
```

Obviously you can write a lot more data than the example above. If you have several nodes, create a dictionary for each one and store them all in an array. Write the array to NSUserDefaults.

Keep in mind that you can only store objects in a dictionary and not primitives like int, float, etc... That is why you have to convert them into NSNumber.

Comment: Okay, but then I could also just use a plist, and that would work easier because it has an editor.

Comment: @blackwolf123333 - It's a matter of personal preference and what works better for your task.