# Store NSArray in persistent (user) data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, sprite-kit, persistence

I need to make my inventory array persistent (does not reset each time the app is closed and reopened).  I currently use a GameState singleton class to store my high score, player level, etc.  These have all been integers so far and are pretty straight forward to use.

I followed the attached tutorial with regards to the GameState singleton class: http://www.raywenderlich.com/63578/make-game-like-mega-jump-spritekit-part-22

I now need to store an array of my inventory which is a custom SKSpriteNode subclass.

Can I store this array in my singleton class and what syntax would I need to approach that?

In order to save the array would I need to set up Encoding/Decoding?  I saw that was a different approach which seems way more complicated than the singleton class.

I am well versed in SQL but would prefer not to use SQLlite if I can instead retrieve the array directly as if it was stored locally.

Comment: What does your array contain?

Comment: A subclass of SKSpriteNode.  I could make this a regular class and store the SKSpriteNode texture as a property.

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults to store an array. Look at this link for an example on how to use NSUserDefaults http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423979/can-you-save-the-position-of-a-node-in-an-sks-file/25428510#25428510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` knows about `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, and `NSDictionary`, so the easiest thing is to store the data you need to save in some combination of those data types. If you can't do that, you'll need to implement `NSCoding` in your custom class so you can archive its instances as `NSData` objects, which isn't as hard as it sounds: http://sam.roon.io/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding.

Personally, I'd start by splitting your model from your view (take the "data" part of your Sprite Kit objects and put them into separate, data-only classes or structs). That should make it easier to reason about what needs to be serialized.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. That link is the missing... "Link" I have been looking for. I think separating the data from the view is a great idea and will allow me to easily archive/unarchive the array in NSData.  I will test and mark this if it works as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: SKSpriteNode conforms to NSCoding, but why would you want to store all that data?

Comment: I need to store the players inventory or else my users will hate me :)  I can either store a subclass of SKSpriteNode with the additional properties I need or I can subclass a standard object and create the SKSpriteNode at runtime.

Comment: Can you simply save the inventory as a description (such as "BagsOfGold") and a value (such as 3) or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: I will need to save information whether it is equipped or not, player bonuses, if it is part of a set, and the cost. So a bunch of bools and ints. Basically, it's an armor class that follows pretty traditional games.